# Silverstripe Installation - no login informations

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I just installed silverstripe (installer v4.7.3) freshly via Composer (v2.0.12) and set the .env file with my database data.
The database was then initialised by calling up the page. However, I was never asked for login information during the installation and none was displayed after the database initialisation was completed. However, the login in the CMS area requires user data, which I do not have now.
The database table "Members" is also empty, even after several installation attempts. (On Windows with XAMP v3.2.4)
How can I log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
You just have to add following lines in your .env-file

```
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME="admin"
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD="password"
```